# iOS Local Notifications and APN: what can I use it for?

Tags: ios, notifications, push, local, apn

After reading Apple Developer Program License Agreement I have some questions about a usage of Local notifications and APN:

There is a paragraph in Agreement (Attachment 1 §2.2):

**You may not use the APN or Local Notifications for the purposes** of advertising, product promotion, or direct marketing of any kind (e.g., up-selling, cross-selling, etc.), including, but not limited to, sending any messages **to promote the use of Your Application or advertise the availability of new features** or versions. Notwithstanding the foregoing, You may use the APN or Local Notifications for promotional purposes in connection with Your Pass so long as such use is directly related to the Pass, e.g., a store coupon may be sent to Your Pass in Wallet.

In my game I want:

a) notify user via Local Notifications after a long (several days) inactivity in the game (every app launch will snooze a notification for a few days ahead)

b) notify users via APN about new levels are available to download

Is APN and Local Notification are legal to implement a) and b)?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Try ask this kind of questions somewhere else like stack exchange. You'll have better chance there. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not a programming question as @Mojtaba Hosseini said in comment:

**Yes**. You can advertise anything about your app and it's levels and features and it's completely legal. But you should not advertise anything that is not related to the current app that received notification.

Comment: Thanks for helping others. but when asker asks a question that is not about programming itself, try have a point to it and be aware of down voters. ;)

Comment: Thanks @MojtabaHosseini. I updated my answer and point it out. I'm new contributor and I didn't knew that.

Comment: @Clan But what does it means that you cannot 'advertise the availability of new features'? New features in this app or some external features? It's not clear

Comment: It says **not limited to** ... advertise the availability of new features or versions

Comment: @Clan I'm not native english speaker, but as I can understand Apple provides not full list of prohibited behaviors, which include: 'product promotion', 'direct marketing', 'promote the use of Your Application', 'advertise the availability of new features',.. Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Apple doesn't access to your future push notifications. Imagine you download a taxi app and let it send you notifications, so you know when your taxi arrives. But suddenly it starts sending you advertises with push notification. It disturbs you. So apple said **You may not**, and not said **You MUST not**. So think about end user before sending any push notification.